# Scanner.throwFor() with mocked input and output

Tags: java, testing, input, junit, mocking

I have a class with several tests, which if run alone pass. Instead, if I run the entire test class, only one passes.

I am testing if the output (ie a String) is equal to an expected String. The output is produced by a method, which requires user keyboard input. In each test, I mock the user input with the following class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class MockInOut {
    private PrintStream orig;
    private InputStream irig;
    private ByteArrayOutputStream os;
    private ByteArrayInputStream is;

    private final static Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();

    public MockInOut(String input) {
        orig = System.out;
        irig = System.in;

        os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            System.setOut(new PrintStream(os, false, charset.name()));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }

        is = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes());
        System.setIn(is);
    }

    /**
     * Returns everything written to System.out since this {@code MockInOut} was
     * constructed. Can't be called on a closed {@code MockInOut}
     */
    public String getOutput() {
        if (os != null) {
            try {
                return os.toString(charset.name()).replace("\r\n", "\n");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        } else {
            throw new Error("getOutput on closed MockInOut!");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Restores System.in and System.out
     */
    public void close() {
        os = null;
        is = null;
        System.setOut(orig);
        System.setIn(irig);
    }
}
```

Each test is structured as follows:

```
@Test
MyClassForConstructor myclassfc = new MyClassForConstructor();
MyClass myclass = new MyClass(myclassfc);

MockInOut userkeyboardinput = new MockInOut("firstLineInput\nsecondLineInput\nthirdLineInput\n");

MyObject myobToGetTested = myclass.methodThatRequiresInput();

MyObject myobExpected = new MyObject(String par1, String par2, String par3);

assertEquals(myobExpected.toString(), myobToGetTested.toString());

userkeyboardinput.close();
```

Each test has the same structure and what it changes is the keyboard input and the parameters to create the expected object.

Every test throws a NoSuchElementException at Scanner.throwFor() because needInput = false, at Scanner.next(), except for one test (always the same, but which has no explicit difference with the others: in the test that passes, I saw that needInput is set true, but I don't know the reason).

I really don't know what else could be done, thanks for everybody who will help!

Comment: Clearly `methodThatRequiresInput()` wants to read more data than what you mock-stuff into your MockInOut - for example, it wants more than `firstLineInput`, `secondLineInput`, and `thirdLineInput`. Perhaps it wants a 4th line. Debug your code (step through it, or add a bunch of sysout statements if you don't want to learn how to use a debugger), and figure out why. You didn't paste the body of methodThatRequiresInput, hence, this question cannot be answered in sufficient detail for SO. Vote-to-close.

Comment: No, i verified and debugged several times and the inputs are all right, even because the single tests pass when they are executed alone. Yeah, i'd like to post the code of the method, but it doesnt add much more: it just produce an object with characteristics dependencing on the input strings.

Comment: The exception also is always thrown on the first line input

Comment: So your theory is: Java is bugged? Or: Please debug this mehod that I didn't paste in SO. Come on, walk a mile in the shoes of someone who might answer this question and think about what they'd need. There are various methods in scanner that look for a specific kind of thing and will keep scanning until then, that would for example explain it. That and a million more things.